# HOW to get the same ENVI result in IDL using CONVOL function?

Tags: idl-programming-language, envi

I am using ENVI to perform a convolution,

With Median set, a kernel size of 5, and an Image Add Back value of 0%

The results in ENVI are really good,

When I try to do the same using CONVOL in IDL I can’t manage to get it to work the same way,

Here is my code:

```
fsize = 5
ext = [fsize, fsize]
kernel = REPLICATE(1, ext[0], ext[1])
B = BYTE(CONVOL(B, kernel, INVALID=255, MISSING=255, /CENTER, /EDGE_WRAP))
```

Can someone tell me what’s wrong?

Comment: Have you tried reversing your kernel?  IDL does not do this prior to computing the convolution.  So if you check out their [documentation](https://www.exelisvis.com/docs/CONVOL.html), you will notice that they suggest using the reverse of the kernel on input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use CONVOL. You are actually doing a median filter, so you should use the MEDIAN function:

```
result = MEDIAN(array, 5)
```